# Pass a variable to a value attribute in slider()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider and the result (numbers) is displayed in the div with id #output.

So I want to pass this variable also to an input field with id #sites, but I'm stucking. How I can change the value attribute with .val()?

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( function() {
    var out = $('#output');
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
          min: 1,
          max: 50,

      slide: function(evt, ui) {
        out.html(ui.value);
      }

    });
    $("#sites").val(out);
  } );
 });
```

Comment: `slide: function(evt, ui) { out.html(ui.value); $("#sites").val(ui.value); }`

Comment: `$("#sites").val(out.innerHtml);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that you only need one document.ready handler. To fix your actual issue, place the code that sets the value of `#sites` *within* the `slide` handler. At the moment you only set the value on load of the page before the user has interacted with the control Try this:

```
$(function() {
  var $out = $('#output');

  $("#slider" ).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 50,
    slide: function(evt, ui) {
      $out.html(ui.value);
      $("#sites").val(ui.value);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: it works, but only for the first time. When I change the slider. It does not update the value attribute in the input field

Answer (score 0):

try   `$("#sites").val(out.text());`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in the slide callback:

```
slide: function(evt, ui) {
   out.html(ui.value);
   $("#sites").val(ui.value);
}
```

Because slide event happens when user interacts with the slider and you are trying to set the value outside at document ready block. At this point of time the value is at slider's defaults value.

```
$(document).ready(function() { // this is as same as
  $( function() { // this one. extra doc ready block is not needed.
   ......
  });
});
```